# How to check difference between two objects in Java and avoid NPE?

Tags: java, coding-style

I've got class

```
public class CallDTO {

private String id;
private Integer callOrigin;
private CustomerDTO callCustomer;
private Integer callType;
private Integer callStatus;
private UserDTO user;
private CustomerDTO callBillingCustomer;
private Date callLogDate;
private Date callRespondDate;
private Date callSolveDate;
private Date callCloseDate;
private String callContactName;
private String callContactTel;
private String callWorkshop;
private String callCustRefNum;
private String callLastComment;
private String checked;
```

...
}

And i need to write a method, that get 2 objects of that class (newCall from REST controller and oldCall from DB) and log all the changes.

For UserDTO and CustomerDTO i need to check it's ids.

The issue is that all the fields (except id) could be Null. And if the value of the field was null of changed to null i need to log some Empty value:
f.e. i've got oldCall.getCallLogDate() == null and e\newCall.getCallLogDate() != null, so i need to write smth like : "Call logging time was changed! Old value was [empty], new value is ...";

What is the best way to write this method in a clean way?
Java 8 is acceptable

Comment: This is not a code writing service. It is unclear why you can not write this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The [java.util.Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) utility class introduced in JDK 7 has a neat null-safe [equals(Object, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method you could use:

```
if (!Objects.equals(oldCall.getCallLogDate(), newCall.getCallLogDate()) {
    System.out.println("Some useful message...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a **horrible** design of a class. The class should be modularized to smaller pieces. For example, notice that many of your fields' names are prefixed with `call*`. It should be a clear sign that those fields should belong to some class containing `Call` information.

There are many solutions for comparing objects null-safe way. Consider using:

- `Objects.equals` from JDK
- `ObjectUtils` from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html)